# compare 2 variables in php

Tags: php, variables

```
if ($ct >= $count){
  echo "ct=$ct and count=$count</br>";
  echo "a";     
  return 0; //No record deleted in the datatable
}elseif ($ct < $count){
  echo "ct=$ct and count=$count</br>";
  echo "b";     
  return 1; //Record deleted in the datatable
}
```

The output is:

```
ct=1 and count=2
a
```

That means "1 >= 2" is true.... How is that possible??? How can I fix it???? I'm driving crazy with this code ... That's the first time happening something like that

Comment: Where are your variables set?

Comment: Your snippet works as intended for me. Did you change the values and are getting a cached result, maybe?

Comment: `var_dump($ct, $count);`

Comment: @Script47 they were set above the `if` statement, but were edited out

Comment: I haven't tried this to verify it, but I believe `$ct = true` would have this effect.

Comment: I'll explain you better.... If I set it $ct=1 and $count=2 so, they are working but, they are coming from a function call

Comment: What @Don'tPanic says.  `true` is evaluated as `true` ignoring the `>= $count` and `true` prints as `1`.

Comment: Making `var_dump($ct>= $count)` i get this result `bool(true) int(2)`

Answer (score 2):

if `$ct` is a boolean, then in this expression:

```
if ($ct >= $count){
```

`$count` will be converted to a boolean for the comparison. A non-zero number will evaluate to true, so the condition `$ct >= $count` will be satisfied, because `true == true`.

In this expression:

```
echo "ct=$ct and count=$count</br>";
```

The boolean `true` is converted to a string, and the string equivalent of `true` is `'1'`.

Comment: According to the var_dump results in your comment under the question, it is a boolean.

Comment: Apparently it isn't _supposed to be_ a boolean, but somehow it is. I would say you need to examine how `$ct` is getting created. Something is going wrong there.

Comment: In java I got this code `var plvl_count = datadets.length;` and I'm sending this variable in php with method: POST. In php I'm calling that function `function cprecords($connect, $pid, $ct){`

Comment: I'm more of a PHP guy than a JavaScript guy, but I don't know of a way that `.length` will return a boolean. Can you show how PHP gets the value from JS? Is it JSON-encoded? Are you reading it from $_POST? Edit your question to show some of that code if you can. It can be difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: I fixed it putting `$ct=(int)$ct;` and `$count=(int)$count;`

Comment: That's good, but it may not be a true solution. If `$ct` really is supposed to be an int to begin with, but it's a boolean instead, forcing the boolean to an int means it will only ever have a value of 1 or 0, not an actual count value.

Comment: That's right but, $ct is the lenght of an array so I'm sure that's not a boolean value.

Comment: This is the only answer and here's the demonstration http://rextester.com/live/DTF57180 +1